# Determine distribution from density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Suppose
>   $$
> f(x)= \begin{cases} cxe^{-2x}, & x\ge 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
> $$
>   is the density function. Determine $c$ and find the distribution function.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? My teacher has already given me the solution, but I don't think it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: What part of the solution do you think is not correct? Want to update the question with specific solution to make it easier to guide you?

Comment: @gt6989b brain fart.  Yes, $1$!

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of a probability density, we must have $\int_{\Omega} f = 1$, where $\Omega$ is the support of the random variable.

That is, we must have
$$\int_0^{\infty} ce^{-2x} \; dx = 1.$$
Solving for $c$, we get: 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2x} \; dx & = \frac{1}{c} \\
\frac{1}{2} & = c \\
c & = 2.
\end{align*}
Alternatively, we could recognize the density function as the form of an exponential distribution, which has density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ with parameter $\lambda > 0$, which takes support on the non-negative real line.